# reference dict element from another one?

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

Is it possible in python one dict element to reference another ?
F.e. :

```
h = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2 }
h['c'] = \h[a]

print h['c']
1

h['a'] = 12
print h['c']
12
```

---

I see :

```
In [382]:  h = { 1: {6:7}, 3:4 }

In [383]: h
Out[383]: {1: {6: 7}, 3: 4}

In [384]: h[5]=h[1]

In [385]: h
Out[385]: {1: {6: 7}, 3: 4, 5: {6: 7}}

In [386]: h[1][6] = 13

In [387]: h
Out[387]: {1: {6: 13}, 3: 4, 5: {6: 13}}
```

trying to build tree, bottom-up.

Comment: Not if you are using integers.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Your example is unclear in multiple ways. Why is there a backslash in your second line? Also in the second line, what is variable `a`--did you mean string `'a'`? And so on.

Comment: I 100% do not see how this functionality is relevant for building a tree structure. In a tree you can't even have two different references to the same node.

Comment: every parent have children and i need to build it bottom-up  ... and during the merge process the nodes are removed and added.. it starts as list and the result is a tree (dict)..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can certainly point elements in a dictionary to another element.  When you assign `h['c']` to `h['a']`, they now share the same memory location:

```
h = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2 }
h['c'] = h['a']
h['c'] is h['a']
True
```

However, many types in Python are something called *immutable*.  They cannot be changed once they are created.  `int` is one of those types, (as are `str`, `tuple`, and others).  So once you change `h['a']`, `h['c']` is no longer pointing to it, since it is now a different object.

```
h['a'] = 12
h['c'] is h['a']
False
```

However, if `h['a']` is a *mutable* type (this includes `list`, `dict`, and others), when you point `h['c']` to `h['a']`, and mutate `h['a']`, that change will be reflected in `h['c']` as well, as `h['c']` is pointing to the same object that `h['a']` is.

Here is a very simple example using a list:

```
dct = {'x': [1,2,3]}
dct['y'] = dct['x']    
dct['y'] is dct['x']   
True

dct['x'][0] = 5
dct['y'] is dct['x']
True

dct
{'x': [5, 2, 3], 'y': [5, 2, 3]}
```